# Regex - Detect all *separated* usernames in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to detect all usernames following this form:

```
/@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,30}/
```

For example, in the following string

```
@eminem is singing with @rihanna
```

, the method must return

```
["@eminem", "@rihanna"]
```

I have tried the following:

```js
function matchAllUsernames(str) {
  const pattern = /@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,30}/g;
  return [...str.matchAll(pattern)].flat();
}

const str = "@eminem is singing with @rihanna";

console.log(matchAllUsernames(str));
```

But... what if I try with this string?

```
@eminem@ndsoiosd is singing with @rihanna
```

In this case, the method must ignore @eminem and @ndsoiosd, because there is no sparation between them...

```js
function matchAllUsernames(str) {
  const pattern = /@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,30}/g;
  return [...str.matchAll(pattern)].flat();
}

const str = "@eminem@ndodshuoc is singing with @rihanna";

console.log(matchAllUsernames(str));
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match consecutive mentions and discard those matches and only extract mentions from other contexts:

```js
function matchAllUsernames(str) {
  const pattern = /(?:@[\w.-]{3,30}){2,}|(@[\w.-]{3,30})/g;
  return Array.from(str.matchAll(pattern), x=>x[1]).filter(Boolean);
}

const str = "@sia@ndodshuoc and @eminem are singing with @rihanna";
console.log(matchAllUsernames(str));
```

Note that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is equal to `\w`.

The `(?:@[\w.-]{3,30}){2,}|(@[\w.-]{3,30})` regex matches two or more sequences of 3 to 30 word, `.` or `-` chars, or captures into Group 1 a sequence of 3 to 30 word, `.` or `-` chars (in another context).

Comment: the underscore is included when using \w ?

Comment: @Raul Yes, you can easily check this on any regex testing site, like `http://regex101.com`. E.g. `@[\w.-]{3,30}` will match `@abc_123___ABZ`.

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend an anchor for a non word boundary before the @ and assert a whitespace boundary to the right at the end of the pattern:

```
\B@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,30}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jeYB5a/1)

```js
function matchAllUsernames(str) {
  const pattern = /\B@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,30}(?!\S)/g;
  return [...str.matchAll(pattern)].flat();
}

const str = "@eminem@ndodshuoc is singing with @rihanna";

console.log(matchAllUsernames(str));
```

To support also the characters `.` and `-` not being allowed before the next @ sign:

```
(?<!\S)@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,30}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ybp5X9/1)